# How do I set hostname in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my `docker-compose.yml` file, I have the following. However the container does not pick up the hostname value. Any ideas?

```yaml
dns:
  image: phensley/docker-dns
  hostname: affy
  domainname: affy.com
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock
```

When I check the hostname in the container it does not pick up `affy`.

Comment: What version of Compose are you using?

Comment: This issue is still open here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2925 You can set hostname but it is not reachable from other containers. So it is mostly useless.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if `version:` isn't specified then docker-compose assumes the file format is v1; see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#versioning

Answer (score 178, accepted):

As of Docker [Compose file version 3.0 and later](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir), you can just use the `hostname` key:

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  yourservicename:
    hostname: your-name
```

Comment: Hmm, docker-compose is not to v3.0 at this time. V2.x is current. Also note that the `version` key is no longer needed in docker-compose.yaml at all.  (The `version` key was not the docker-compose version when it still existed, but the compose spec version.)

Comment: There is no use for the `version:` key any more. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/04-version-and-name/

"Top-level version property is defined by the specification for backward compatibility but is only informative."

Answer (score 99):

I found that the hostname was not visible to other containers when using `docker run`. This turns out to be a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2925) (perhaps more a known feature), with part of the discussion being:

> We should probably add a warning to the docs about using hostname. I think it is rarely useful.

The correct way of assigning a hostname - in terms of container networking - is to [define an alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) like so:

```
services:
  some-service:
    networks:
      some-network:
        aliases:
          - alias1
          - alias2
```

Unfortunately this *still* doesn't work with `docker run`. The workaround is to assign the container a name:

```
docker-compose run --name alias1 some-service
```

And `alias1` can then be pinged from the other containers.

**UPDATE:** As @grilix points out, you should use `docker-compose run --use-aliases` to make the defined aliases available.

Comment: I'm stuck with that problem that I can't access container by hosname from other containers. And you're the only one in whole internet who stated this problem.. been googling for 20 hours already

Comment: Same here! It's insane that millions of developers seem to use Docker, but nobody knows how to give a box a simple name, not even the offiicial docs. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just in case, now we can use `--use-aliases` with `docker-compose run`. This will avoid hardcoding the alias on the `run` command

Answer (score 65):

This seems to work correctly.  If I put your config into a file:

```
$ cat > compose.yml <<EOF
dns:
  image: phensley/docker-dns
  hostname: affy
  domainname: affy.com
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock
EOF
```

And then bring things up:

```
$ docker-compose -f compose.yml up
Creating tmp_dns_1...
Attaching to tmp_dns_1
dns_1 | 2015-04-28T17:47:45.423387 [dockerdns] table.add tmp_dns_1.docker -> 172.17.0.5
```

And then check the hostname inside the container, everything seems to be fine:

```
$ docker exec -it stack_dns_1 hostname
affy.affy.com
```

Comment: What version of Compose are you using?

Comment: This format doesn't work in the latest version of docker-compose.  YML files are finicky things; are you sure this is the right format for dns?

Comment: YML files aren't really all that finicky.  What does "doesn't work" mean?  According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), both `hostname` and `domainname` are valid `docker-compose.yml` options. Update: just tested, still seems to work just fine (docker-compose version 1.4.2, docker version 1.8.2).

Comment: Is there any way to expose this hostname outside of the docker environment? It would be nice if the host could access the docker containers by their dns name.

Comment: That is possible, and probably worth it's own question.  If you search for "docker dns" you will find several relevant results; take a look at what's out there first.

Answer (score 50):

Based on docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/command

I simply put
`hostname: <string>`
in my docker-compose file.

E.g.:

```
[...]

lb01:
  hostname: at-lb01
  image: at-client-base:v1

[...]
```

and container lb01 picks up `at-lb01` as hostname.

Comment: if you have multiple containers in the docker-compose file, would you set the hostname for each container? that seems very inefficient?

Comment: If you need well-known names for containers that's a viable solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed:
You can find the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way I have found is to just set the container name in the `docker-compose.yml` See [container_name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#container_name) documentation. It is applicable to docker-compose v1+. It works for container to container, not from the host machine to container.

```
services:
  dns:
    image: phensley/docker-dns
    container_name: affy
```

Now you should be able to access `affy` from other containers using the container name. I had to do this for multiple redis servers in a development environment.

**NOTE** The solution works so long as you don't need to scale. Such as consistant individual developer environments.

Comment: In `Compose 3.7` the only way I got the database service hostname to be seen from within another service container of the same stack was to name the service as the hostname. Using the `hostname:` property failed. Using the environment HOSTNAME= construct failed too.

Comment: Another solution that also worked, was to use the `aliases` property as described in the `foz` solution.

Comment: This works great but is a bit messy - I've now taken to setting `container_name` and `hostname` to the same value to achieve what I need

Comment: One problem with `container_name` is that it's global to the local host system so you run into conflicts when trying to run multiple stacks and two different services have the same `container_name`.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to spin [freeipa container](https://hub.docker.com/r/freeipa/freeipa-server/) to have a working kdc and had to give it a hostname otherwise it wouldn't run.
What eventually did work for me is setting the `HOSTNAME` env variable in compose:

```
version: 2
services:
  freeipa:
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=ipa.example.test
```

Now its working:

```
docker exec -it freeipa_freeipa_1 hostname
ipa.example.test
```

Comment: For me, using slim, that results in a HOSTNAME environment variable that has no effect at all on the actual hostname of the container

Comment: While this may have worked with the container you were using, the environment directive only exposes variables to the container. It's still up to the container to do something with the value that's set. In many cases it will likely do nothing.

Comment: exposing an env var has nothing to do with the hostname of the container, they are two separate realms.