# Docker-Compose container ip address with container name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose have a two  service,
and docker-compose.yml define enviroment variable  ip address with container name,

```
 version: '2'

services:
  api:
    build: ./api/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./api:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - dock_net
    container_name: con_api

  web:
    build: ./web/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    networks:
      - dock_net
    container_name: con_web
    environment:
        Ip:con_ip

networks:
  dock_net:
      driver: bridge
```

But variable see "con_ip" not 127.0.0.3

Comment: When you use docker-compose the services on the same network will be visible to each other. So you can use `web` and `api` inside both the containers. Why do you want to use this ip? `web` and `api` host names will automatically resolve to the container IP addresses

Comment: I use django python file , but env variable thats name not seeing ip address

Comment: Not able to understand the problem. Please elaborate in details what you want and why you want the IP

Comment: I can't access container in python file because request  another container And thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that you are properly using environment variables. Please refer [environment variables in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#passing-environment-variables-through-to-containers).

You can access one container from other container simply by using service name of that container. And this is the recommended way.

But if you prefer IP addresses for your own reasons, I am telling you how to set the static ip address of container, i would not recommend it though.

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build: ./api/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./api:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - dock_net:
          ipv4_address: 127.0.0.3
    container_name: con_api

  web:
    build: ./web/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    networks:
      - dock_net:
          ipv4_address: 127.0.0.4
    container_name: con_web

networks:
  dock_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 127.0.0.0/8
         gateway: 127.0.0.1
```

This will assign the required IP-addresses to your containers. `API` will be at `127.0.0.3` and `web` will be at `127.0.0.4`

**EDIT:** If you want to access service named `api` from inside the web container then you can use its ip address as we have allocated here. http://127.0.0.3:80/ or you can also use http://api:80/

The `api` is used in place of IP address because its the service name and when no hostname is given, service name is taken as default hostname. If you want to know about hostnames refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924843/how-do-i-set-hostname-in-docker-compose) question.

Comment: Well, how  I  can access container  with  service name in python file  ?
Because I request  Api web application

And thank you  for your answer :)