# Dokku - get ip address of nginx reverse proxy inside container?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, dokku

In my ASP.NET Core server, I've have forwarding to support my OpenId Connect authentication workflow:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
  {
      options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor;

      // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
      // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit
      // configuration.
      options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
      options.KnownProxies.Clear();
  }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
```

However, I'd like to configure `KnownProxies` (and `KnownNetworks`). Is there a way to find out the ip address of the proxy server (within the context of a container)? Is the configuration static? If not, can it be automated?

Also, is this address going to be the same thing as the Host address. I.e. would resolving the ip address to `host.docker.internal` help? Which doesn't seem to be an easy thing to do within a Linux environment anyway...

Also, the above code comes from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies). Re-reading that section, is it okay to leave the above code alone? I'm assuming that locking down to a particular proxy server would be better?

Comment: I think you should use Environmnet Variables to set your URIs. This could lead your app to be independent from the platform. You can set your environemnt variable through your dockerfile or within your CI/CD pipelines either. Follow [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412799/docker-compose-container-ip-address-with-container-name)

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good way to go. However, in order to do that I need to confirm that the IP address for the proxy server (from the container) in Dukko isn't ephemeral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container IP is ephemeral, and may change across app rebuilds or redeploys. By default, Dokku will run your app on the internal `docker0` network, and the only things that can access the container are services running on the server itself, so allowing access from all network interfaces is safe.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. In that case I'm happy with the code sample!