# NodeJS could not connect to MYSQL inside Docker Container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js

I've complied following docker-compose file, encounter error message.

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    build: ./app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - PORT=3000
      - MYSQL_HOST=ppshein-mysql
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=ppshein123456
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
    - my-bridge-network
    depends_on:
      - "${MYSQL_HOST}"
    container_name: ppshein-api
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.14
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ppshein123456
    networks:
    - my-bridge-network
    container_name: ppshein-mysql
networks:
  my-bridge-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is configuration file for mysql sequelize,

```
"production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "ppshein123456",
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "ppshein-mysql",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "logging": false
}
```

and Here is `Dockerfile` for NodeJS app,

```
FROM node:9.10.1
ENV NODE_ENV=development
COPY ./ /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www/
RUN yarn install && yarn add sequelize-cli -g
EXPOSE 3000
CMD /bin/bash ./wait-for-it.sh ppshein-mysql:3306 -- npm run docker
```

then, finally I encountered following error message:

> Loaded configuration file "config/config.json". Using environment
>   "production". Sat, 26 Jan 2019 01:03:45 GMT sequelize deprecated
>   String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based
>   operators for better security, read more at
>   http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators at
>   node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13
>
> ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:3306

Answer (score 2):

You should not access MySQL on `0.0.0.0`.

Docker-compose define hostnames for containers on same bridge network equals to the container name, so your MySQL hostname is `db`.

If you want to customize your container hostname, you can do it using aliases on network. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264089/3429323

Comment: Inside configuration file, it should be `"host": "db",` instead of "host": "0.0.0.0",?

Comment: Exactly. Or the hostname you define on alias if you opted using it.

Comment: even I've changed like that, it was not working. I've updated my code.

Comment: Try removing every mention to network on your docker-compose.yml. the default network should work just fine.

Comment: I found, that's docker mysql version problem. `mysql:5` only work.