# docker-compose.yml container_name and hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the use of `container_name` in `docker-compose.yml` file? Can I use it as `hostname` which is nothing but the service name in `docker-compose.yml` file.

Also when I explicitly write `hostname` under services does it override the hostname represented by `service name`?

Comment: Probably this can help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924843/how-do-i-set-hostname-in-docker-compose]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`hostname:` just sets what the container believes its own hostname is.  In the unusual event you got a shell inside the container, it might show up in the prompt.  It has no effect on anything outside, and there’s usually no point in setting it.  (It has basically the same effect as **hostname**(1): that command doesn’t cause anything outside your host to know the name you set.)

`container_name:` sets the actual name of the container when it runs, rather than letting Docker Compose generate it.  If this name is different from the name of the block in `services:`, both names will be usable as DNS names for inter-container communication.  Unless you need to use `docker` to manage a container that Compose started, you usually don’t need to set this either.

If you omit both of these settings, one container can reach another (provided they’re in the same Docker Compose file and have compatible `networks:` settings) using the name of the `services:` block and the port the service inside the container is listening in.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports: [6033:3306]
  app:
    build: .
    ports: [12345:8990]
    env:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
```

Comment: `container_name: <mycontainer>` has the benefit that you have nice container names when doing `docker ps` or listing containers or other operations. Otherwise `container_name` is automatically assigned a name like `<docker_compose_folder>_<service_name>_<incrementing_number_of_containers_with_same_name>`.

Comment: It means one has to be carefull of not overriding `container_name` with generic names like db, mysql, app, etc. I usually define a `PREFIX` variabile in `.env` and use it like this: `container_name: ${PREFIX}-db`.

Comment: There is a point to setting the hostname, directly or indirectly, when your container expects the same name between first boot and future boots, such as when creating a replica-set in mongodb.  It hardcodes the hostname in its configuration, and if it is random, it causes issues.

Comment: Setting `hostname` also configures an `alias`. If you run `getent host <hostname>` from another container on the same network, it should resolve to the other container's IP.

Comment: @JohnChristopher Instead of manually defining a prefix, you could also use the project name, for example: `container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-webserver"`

Comment: @Martin That's pretty much exactly the name Compose will pick on its own if you don't set `container_name:`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Not exactly, this way the `-1` suffix is omitted.

Answer (score 32):

The easiest answer is the following:

**container_name:** This is the container name that you see from the host machine when listing the running containers with the `docker container ls` command.

**hostname:** The hostname of the container. Actually, the name that you define here is going to the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
$ exec -it myserver /bin/bash

bash-4.2# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
172.18.0.2  myserver
```

That means you can ping machines by that names within a Docker network.

I highly suggest set these two parameters the same to avoid confusion.

**An example docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    database-server:
        image: ...
        container_name: database-server
        hostname: database-server
        ports:
            - "xxxx:yyyy"

    web-server:
        image: ...
        container_name: web-server
        hostname: web-server
        ports:
            - "xxxx:xxxx"
            - "5101:4001" # debug port
```

Comment: `hostname` is written only to the host file of one container, the one run by the service. It's not written to the host file of every services run with docker compose. You ping machines by `container_name`, not `hostname`.

Comment: For those wondering, you do not need to set either of `container_name` or `hostname` to be able to reference your containers for example in URLs. You can simply use the block name of the service in your `docker-compose.yml` file, even though the container's actual name (shown for example with `docker ps -a`) will be an auto-generated name.

Comment: Can you complement the answer with domainname, to differentiate them?

Comment: @JohnChristopher Setting `hostname` also configures an `alias`. If you run `getent host <hostname>` from another container on the same network, it should resolve to the other container's IP.

Answer (score 3):

you can customize the image name to build & container name during **docker-compose up** for this, you need to mention like below in **docker-compose.yml** file.
It will create an image & container with custom names.

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend_dev:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: "mycustomname/sample:v1"
    container_name: mycustomname_sample_v1
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```