# Can't connect PostgreSQL db to Spring with docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am having issues connecting my Spring app to db with docker. Can someone give me advice what could be wrong?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=changeme

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

docker ps

`7798a7328c2b postgres "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago   Up 5 hours   5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5433/tcp, :::5433->5433/tcp   postgres_container`

docker-compose

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-changeme}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I am getting bunch of errors when trying to run the app
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEKD8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using your container_name of the postgres service instead of localhost.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres_container:5433/postgres
```

Here is a post explaining why:

[docker-compose.yml container_name and hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522620/docker-compose-yml-container-name-and-hostname)

Comment: Yes, and container_name is not really neaded. You then can use `postgress` instead of `postgres_container`