# Consistent container names with docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an nginx config file with a line such as:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://my-container:1234;
}
```

Problem is, this changes over time, depending on which machine, to things like:

> my-container-my-container-1 
> my-container_my-container-1 
> my-container-my-container_1

How do I keep docker container names consistent when working with docker-compose.yml files?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        ports:
            - 80:80
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - my-container
    my-container:
        build: .
        expose:
            - 1234
```

Comment: Regardless of how compose or swarm names the container, the service name and network alias is `my-container`. What is the error you are trying to solve, and can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose.yml container\_name and hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522620/docker-compose-yml-container-name-and-hostname)