# Browser request hanging when running the latest Docker ColdFusion image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, coldfusion

I installed the Docker release of ColdFusion with the following command:

```
docker pull eaps-docker-coldfusion.bintray.io/cf/coldfusion:latest
```

I then created a compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  coldfusion:
    image: eaps-docker-coldfusion.bintray.io/cf/coldfusion:latest
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    networks:
      coldfusion:
    hostname: coldfusion
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/coldfusion/volumes/app:/app"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/coldfusion/volumes/logs:/opt/coldfusion/cfusion/logs"
    environment:
      acceptEULA: "YES"
      password: "ColdFusion123"
      enableSecureProfile: "false"
      HOST_USER_ID: ${CURRENT_UID}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${CURRENT_GID}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:8500 || exit 1
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
networks:
  coldfusion:
    name: coldfusion
  common:
    external: true
    name: common
```

and started it with the command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-dev.yml coldfusion
```

The log shows:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~/dev/docker/projects/coldfusion$ docker service logs -f coldfusion_coldfusion
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Updating webroot to /app
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Configuring virtual directories
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Updating password
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Skipping language updation
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Serial Key: Not Provided
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Previous Serial Key: Not Provided
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Starting ColdFusion
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Starting ColdFusion 2018 server ...
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | The ColdFusion 2018 server is starting up and will be available shortly.
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | ======================================================================
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | ColdFusion 2018 server has been started.
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | ColdFusion 2018 will write logs to /opt/coldfusion/cfusion/bin/../logs/coldfusion-out.log
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | ======================================================================
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | [000] Checking server startup status...
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | External Addons: Disabled
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | External Session Storage: Disabled
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Skipping setup script invocation
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Secure Profile: Disabled
coldfusion_coldfusion.1.rlhixv3jctvm@stephane-pc    | Cleaning up setup directories
```

But it hangs when typing the `http://localhost:8500/` request in the browser.

The log remains empty:

```
tail -f volumes/logs/coldfusion-out.log
```

I created an `index.cfm` page in the `/app` directory:

```
hi
<cfset firstName = "World">

Hello <cfoutput>#firstName#</cfoutput>!

This CFML tutorial was designed for
<cfif firstName eq "World">
  you!
<cfelse>
  the world to see.
</cfif>
```

UPDATE: A 200 response comes back fine when using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Opening the firewall ports does not change anything to the issue:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~$ sudo ufw allow from 127.0.0.0 to any port 8500;
Rules updated
stephane@stephane-pc:~$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 8500;
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

My host `/etc/hosts` file contains the line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

The `nmap` command responds:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~/dev/docker/projects/coldfusion$ nmap -p 8500 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-08 12:09 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00038s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8500/tcp open  fmtp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.22 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docker compose file shows

```
hostname: coldfusion
```

so shouldn't it be available at http://coldfusion:8500?

If it's [docker compose v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291253/11047), it should be

```
services:
  dns:
    hostname: 'your-domain'
```

Comment: I removed the `hostname:` property and added the entry `dev.coldfusion` in the `/etc/hosts` file. I can now view the page at `http://dev.coldfusion:8500/`